# Nesting BsonDocuments in MongoDB queries

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection setup where each document's JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "Stuff",
    "project_id" : "1234",
    "VehicleEntry" : [
        {
            // Irrelevant fields removed.
            "VehicleStatus" : "PASSED"
        },
        {
            // Irrelevant fields removed.
            "VehicleStatus" : "FAILED"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to write a query that gives me the number of vehicles passed and failed for each project identifier. I have done so in this very long aggregation query:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(new BsonDocument
    {
        {
            "project_id", "1234"
        }
    })
    .Unwind(i => i["VehicleEntry"])
    .Group(new BsonDocument
    {
        {
            "_id", "$project_id"
        },
        {
            "passed", new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "$sum", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {
                            "$cond", new BsonArray
                            {
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {
                                        "$eq", new BsonArray 
                                        {
                                            "$VehicleEntry.VehicleStatus", 
                                            "PASSED"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                1,
                                0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "failed", new BsonDocument
            {
                {
                    "$sum", new BsonDocument
                    {
                        {
                            "$cond", new BsonArray
                            {
                                new BsonDocument
                                {
                                    {
                                        "$eq", new BsonArray
                                        {
                                            "$VehicleEntry.VehicleStatus",
                                            "FAILED"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                1,
                                0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

While it works as expected, this seems very difficult to maintain and has even become unreadable. How can I improve the way this is written to be more maintainable?

If it's relevant to a better solution, I already have the Newtonsoft library in my project as I use it to convert Json to Bson.

**EDIT** I have been told I could serialize Bson to do this, but I am not familiar with the concept. What are some best practices for that and how can I convert this query to use serialized bson?

Answer (score 2):

I found one way to simplify this which helps break up the number of rows required.

Following [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120629/can-i-do-a-text-query-with-the-mongodb-c-sharp-driver) about converting a JSON string to Bson, I wrote part of my query as it would be in a console. I could only figure out how to do this for the match and group part:

```
var matchJSON = "{ project_id : '1234' }";
var groupJSON = "{ " + 
    "_id : { project_id : '$project_id', date : '$VehicleEntry.@Date' }, " + 
    "passed : { $sum : { $cond : [ { $eq : [ '$VehicleEntry.VehicleStatus', 'PASSED' ] }, 1, 0 ] } }, " + 
    "failed : { $sum : { $cond : [ { $eq : [ '$VehicleEntry.VehicleStatus', 'FAILED' ] }, 1, 0 ] } } }";
```

Then I converted it to BsonDocuments:

```
var matchBson = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(matchJSON);
var groupBson = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(groupJSON);
```

and then ran my aggregate query just like it was previously:

```
var aggregate = collection.Aggregate()
    .Match(matchBson)
    .Unwind(i => i["VehicleEntry"])
    .Group(groupBson);
```